# How can I load external JSON files into my test in Angular 2?

Tags: json, testing, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm writing some tests for an Angular 2 app that needs to mock a big JSON structure. I want to put that that JSON in its own file so that I can import it on other tests as well. In using Jasmine with Karma.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. This one targets Angular (v2 and above). The quoted o one is related to AngularJS (v.1) Different beasts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options:

- Put the JSON in a javascript file (as a global variable) and load that javascript file by adding an "include" in your karma configuration file.
- Use a script loader (such as requirejs or another AMD script loader) to load your js file.
- Add a service or constant to your angular module in a standalone javascript file, then you should be able to retrieve it from your test file.

The best option probably depends on how you are loading your scripts at the minute. Assuming the Angular code is split into multiple files, how do you ensure all the files are loaded?

If you just import the files manually in the correct order and use the global variable window.angular to define your modules, then option 1 or 3 is best. If you already use an AMD loader then option 2 is worth considering.

Comment: The answer by Siddharth Ajmera is an excellent description of how you would do option 3.